# How do I go about setting up multiple internal sites from one server on iis7?

Tags: iis-7, internal-dns, intranet

What I'm essentially aiming to do is have a web server running Win 2008 Standard and IIS7 which will serve internal sites.

The idea is that the sites will be accessed with a setup like the following:

```
Site 1: http://intranet
Site 2: http://intranet2
Site 3: http://intranetsite
```

Would I just create host records called intranet, intranet2, etc on our internal DNS and separate sites with Host Name's of intranet, intranet2 and so on? or would I have to do something else?

Comment: I know this is a duplicate but I can't find the other question.  Will answer for now, until we can find the other!

Comment: Ah nothing came up when I searched. Maybe I was searching for the wrong thing?

Comment: Yeah, I just went through a goodly amout of the Google index and nothing came up.  I'm leaving it, someone else can find it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost on the right track.  Set up one host record for your server and then 3 CNAME records for each of the three URL's you have above pointing to your host record.  3 host records will also work, but the other way is best practice (mainly due to reverse lookup issues with multiple host records).  Then set up one web site for each of them in IIS and use host header redirection to let IIS know which site to send the request to (based on the HTTP host: header from the request).

Here's the Technet article for [**configuring a host header for a web site**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx).