# Configuring multiple website on the Same IIS

Tags: iis-7, sql-server-2008

I have server 2008 installed on one of my servers. I have two domain names, which i want to configure for two different website in IIS7. I already configured one site for one domain name , which is using port 80. How do i configure multiple websites, which can be accessed by different hostnames

thanks

Comment: Same thing as in this question (even though it specifically says internal): http://serverfault.com/questions/68020/how-do-i-go-about-setting-up-multiple-internal-sites-from-one-server-on-iis7

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure each website to respond to the correct host header. This will enable you to serve both sites on the same port on the same server. For example www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com. If you only have one domain, you can specify a different host name (e.g. site1.domain.com and site2.domain.com).

In IIS7 you set the host name in the site bindings dialog box.

Step by step instructions:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Open Administrative Tools
3. Launch Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager (Note: Do not open the 6.0 Manager.)
4. In the connections pane, twirl open the tree until you see the website you've created previously
5. Select the site
6. In the Actions pane, click the Bindings link
7. Select the binding you want to edit
8. Click on the Edit button
9. Add the appropriate host name (e.g. site.domain.com; do not include http:// )
10. Click on OK, then Close

Comment: You need to configure each website to respond to the correct host header. This will enable you to serve both sites on the same port on the same server.-- How do i do this?  Apologies for my ignorance, im not really a server guy :(

Comment: hi,
After configuring the binding settings, when i try to browse the site it returns 404 not found? do i have to do anything else?

Comment: No, a 404 is actually somewhat of a good sign. It means the site is responding to requests. It's likely that you don't have a file in the web root that IIS can serve.